# $T$-Channel matrix element

Tags: quantum-field-theory, kinematics, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams

I’ve been reading an article about the matrix element of the three different channels In Feynman diagrams and I saw this. My question is how did $k^2 - m^2$ (part of the fermion propagator) become $2p2*p4$ in the photo?

[image: T-Channel diagram]

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is a Compton scattering, so wavy line = photon and straight line = electron.

In this case the photon is massless, so $p_4^2 = p_1^2 = 0$.

So expanding the definition of $k$ you find for the denominator

$$k^2 - m^2 = (p_2 - p_4)^2 - m^2 = p_2^2 + p_4 ^2 + 2 p_2\cdot p_4 - m^2 = m^2 + 0 + 2 p_2\cdot p_4 - m^2 = 2 p_2\cdot p_4$$

where $m$ is the mass of the electron of course.

Comment: Oh yes thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it 